# Controls absurd size from SizeChanged event

Tags: c#, silverlight

I got my video player. As long as it loads it is hidden (1 on 1 pixel size applied to object). When it is done loading it fires JavaScript functions and is resized to desired size (640 x 480px i.e.). In effect `SizeChanged` event is fired. In that event handler media element is resized to keep proper aspect ratio.

The problem is from time to time I got absurd size like: `ActualWidth == 448900, ActualHeight == 286090`.

Anyone was having troubles at least similar to this one? I couldn't reproduce it on my test environment so I have no idea how, when and why it does happen. Any suggestions might be helpful.

SizeChanged handler:

```
private void Player_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Size pSize = e.NewSize;
    if (_controlPanel.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
        pSize = new Size(e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height - _controlPanel.PanelRoot.Height);

    _videoPanel.OnParentSizeChanged(pSize);
}
```

VideoPanel.OnParentSizeChanged:

```
public void OnParentSizeChanged(Size newSize)
{
    //nothing to do here
    if (_lastLayoutSize != null &&
        _lastLayoutSize.Width == newSize.Width &&
        _lastLayoutSize.Height == newSize.Height)
        return;

    _lastLayoutSize = new Size(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
    ApplyAspectRatio();
}
```

VideoPanel.ApplyAspectRatio:

```
public void ApplyAspectRatio()
{
    //security checks
    if (_lastLayoutSize == null)
        return;

    if (_mediaSource == null)
    {
        if (_imgThumbnail != null)
        {
            this.Width = _lastLayoutSize.Width;
            this.Height = _lastLayoutSize.Height;
        }

        return;
    }

    if (_mediaSource.Width == 0 || _mediaSource.Height == 0)
        return;

    double dScale = 1.0;
    double dSourceHeight = 1.0;
    double dSourceWidth = 1.0;

    lock (_msSync)
    {
        dSourceWidth = _mediaSource.Width;
        dSourceHeight = _mediaSource.Height;

        double dHeightRatio = 1.0;
        double dWidthRatio = 1.0;

        dHeightRatio = _lastLayoutSize.Height / dSourceHeight;
        dWidthRatio = _lastLayoutSize.Width / dSourceWidth;

        dScale = System.Math.Min(dHeightRatio, dWidthRatio);
    }

    double nWidth = dSourceWidth * dScale;
    double nHeight = dSourceHeight * dScale;

    Width = MaxWidth = MinWidth = nWidth;
    Height = MaxHeight = MinHeight = nHeight;

    this.InvalidateArrange();
}
```

I removed code for logging. It was just writing some text to isolated storage. Those absurd values occures in top of that invocation chain, Player_SizeChanged method.

Comment: Can you show your code of the resizing or rather of your sizeChanged handler?

Comment: Is it possible you're applying resizing multiple times? (event triggers again before event is finished)

Comment: @Destrictor I thought about it and checked it by logging to file starting and ending handling this event, even I don't fire any size changes on that object (only on child of its child). Event was fired once and there was no simultaneous invokes.

Comment: Perhaps try adding to the log the startsize, projected endsize and effective endsize? It might shed some light on the matter.

Comment: @Destrictor are you suggesting logging LastSize, NewSize, and ActualSize (ActualWidth, ActualHeight)? I will givi it a try.